# Write export of selected cells as a .txt file without "quotation marks"

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-csv

I'm working on a Excel sheet that gets a lot of information.
Some columns have information that i need to use in a script and i use the following code I've found to save whatever i select in a .txt file after i click a button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\NumeroChamados.txt"
    Set rng = Selection
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then

            Write #1, cellValue

        Else
            Write #1, cellValue,
        End If
            Next j
        Next i
        Close #1
End Sub
```

Thing is everything i save ends up with quotation marks like the example below:

```
"4146546546523133"
"4285725763131"
"461"
"4230236646435356694197285187451644148"
"4230375763756379653464564"
```

The cells i select usually contain a string from another cell in which i use a macro to get it.

Comment: What does your data look like? I ran the code, exactly as you have it (same directory/filename) on my computer and it just put the straight numbers. I did `304`/`187`,`440`, etc. Does your data have quotes around it?  Also, an aside, your `Else` statement doesn't do anything different ...do you intend to later, or is that missing something?

Comment: Actually the cell extract a string from another cell that contain some text.
The Question is updated.

Comment: How do the cells extract a string from another cell that contain some text. Do those other cells have quote marks around them? Does the formula that does the extracting add quote marks? Are there line feeds or anything like that in either of the cells?

Comment: In order: They extract the very next string after the word "Number". No, they do not have quotes around them. The formula also do no add quotes to whatever is extracted from the original cell. There are some lines in the original cell because it contains all the text from an email's body.

Comment: Can you post some mock-data? I tried doing formulas and it still isn't putting quotes around the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid adding wrapping quotes to anything Excel interprets as a string (even text-that-looks-like-a-number), use `Print` instead of `Write`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\NumeroChamados.txt"
    Set rng = Selection
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                Print #1, cellValue
            Else
                Print #1, cellValue,
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

[image]