# Export to Text without Quotation Marks

Tags: excel, vba, txt

I have multiple worksheets in my workbook.
Each worksheet has two columns of data (ColA and ColC) which I want to print to separate text files.
The attached code results in two text files: “WorksheetTab_LnFn.txt” and “WorksheetTab_FnLn.txt”
The text file saved from my ColA does NOT quotations whilst the second text file saved from my ColC DOES HAVE quotation marks - I want each resulting text file to NOT have quotation marks.

I may have worksheets later with data in ColA, ColC, ColE and ColG, each of which I want to export/save/print to a text file – thus I would want in that case four separate text document, all WITHOUT quotation marks.

The best code I have been able to find is locate is: [Write export of selected cells as a .txt file without "quotation marks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983201) and I have looked at [How to create a text file using excel VBA without having double quotation marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679808/).

I understand most of it, but am not being successful at integrating parts of this code into mine.  Ideally I am seeking to reduce the code and loop so it would process ColA and then ColB without having two separate code blocks.  I did use code I found and made minimal changes, but do not know if the Case LCase line is necessary

```
        'Create FirstName LastName Isolation TXT files
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            For Each sh In Sheets
                Select Case LCase(sh.Name)
                    Case LCase("[COLOR=#0000ff]Master[/COLOR]"), LCase("[COLOR=#0000ff]Info[/COLOR]")
                    Case Else
                        sh.Range("A:A").Copy
                        Workbooks.Add
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sh.Name & "_FnLn.txt", _
                            FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
                        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
                End Select
            Next

        'Create LastName FirstName Isolation TXT files
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            For Each sh In Sheets
                Select Case LCase(sh.Name)
                    Case LCase("[COLOR=#0000ff]Master[/COLOR]"), LCase("[COLOR=#0000ff]Info[/COLOR]")
                    Case Else
                        sh.Range("C:C").Copy
                        Workbooks.Add
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sh.Name & "_LnFn.txt", _
                            FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
                        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
                End Select
            Next
    
            MsgBox "Text Files Created"
        End Sub
```

Comment: You can't have sheet names like `"[COLOR=#0000ff]Master[/COLOR]"`, so why is that there?  Is that code from somewhere else?

Comment: https://chandoo.org/wp/save-range-as-text-using-vba/ has code which does what you want.

Comment: Re the code, yes I had obtain the base code elsewhere but was unable to fiigure out why a blue color would figure into a text document.  I left it in until I could . . . with the assistance of others  . . . eliminate it.

Comment: On the code referral, I will play with it in a couple of minutes.  I have seen CHANDOO code before, but like everything Google, it's in the way you phrase the query.  Thank you for the referral, Tim.

Comment: Tim . . . Exactly as needed.  Will modify to handle the looping through multiple sheets now.  Thank you.

Comment: I am still having issues.  (1) The resulting Text File is outputting not only the rows without quotations, but is also adding all lines (1,048,513) in the spreadsheet; (2) I am not cycling through the worksheets.  If I have three worksheets, it outputs the same text file, but with a different name as coded.  Link to my revised code at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5d8oywpvla36rg/TextWithoutQuotations.txt?dl=0

Comment: You can update your question to add your current code.

Comment: `Set myrng = Range("C:C")` here you are referencing the whole column, when you're only interested in the part which has any data.  You want something more like  `Set myrng = Range("C1:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim filename As String, myrng As Range, sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        
        filename = wb.Path & "\" & sh.Name & "_FnLn.txt"
        Set myrng = sh.Range("C1:C" & sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row) 'use sh reference
        
        RangeToTextFile myrng, filename             'comma-separated
        'RangeToTextFile myrng, filename, vbtab     'e.g. for tab-separated file
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Text Files Created"
End Sub

'write a range `rng` to a text file at `fPath`.  Default separator is comma
Sub RangeToTextFile(rng As Range, fPath As String, Optional separator As String = ",")
    Dim data, r As Long, c As Long, sep, lo As String, ff As Integer
    
    ff = FreeFile()                     'safer than using hard-coded #1
    Open fPath For Output As #ff
    
    If rng.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        ReDim data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)      'handle special case of single cell
        data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    Else
        data = rng.Value                'get all values as an array
    End If
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)        'loop rows
        lo = ""                         'clear line output
        sep = ""                        'clear separator
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)    'loop columns
            lo = lo & sep & data(r, c)  'build the line to be written
            sep = separator             'add separator after first value
        Next c
        Print #ff, lo                   'write the line
    Next r
    Close #ff
End Sub
```

Comment: Solution fast and comments assisted.  Does the hash In the Open, Print and Close have some special significance?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701599/what-does-a-hash-do-to-a-variable-in-vb?answertab=votes#tab-top